# Add Parameters manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle on Aspnet.Core normally reads the needed Parameters from the Method Signature, e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/datasets/{id}")]
[SwaggerOperation("DatasetsIdGet")]
[SwaggerResponse(200, type: typeof(DataSet))]
public IActionResult DatasetsIdGet([FromRoute]string id)
{
    string exampleJson = null;

    var example = exampleJson != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(exampleJson) : default(DataSet);
    return new ObjectResult(example);
}
```

The ID is from the route and is available via the Swagger-UI and generated spec.

Unfortunately, I have to upload some very big files and would like to disable formbinding for a method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
// drain fields manually. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads
// assume that there is the field bigupload.
}
```

Using Swagger-Editor I can easily describe this scenario- but how can I convince Swashbuckle that this Method has bigupload as mandatory field?

## Edit

Here is my Solution based on a thread in the swashbuckle github

```
public class ImportFileParamType : IOperationFilter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds formData Attributes to the Swagger Documentation.
    /// Must be registered in Startup.cs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ok");

        var attributes = context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes()
        .OfType<SwaggerFormParameter>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
            {
                operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
            }

            if (operation.Consumes.Count == 0)
            {
                operation.Consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
            }

            var collectionFormat = attribute.CollectionFormat == CollectionFormat.None ? "" : attribute.CollectionFormat.ToString();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter()
            {
                Name = attribute.Name,
                Description = attribute.Description,
                In = "formData",
                Required = attribute.IsRequired,
                Type = attribute.Type,
                CollectionFormat = collectionFormat
            });
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ok");
    }
}

public enum CollectionFormat
{
    csv,
    ssv,
    tsv,
    pipes,
    None
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds pure FormData Objects to a Swagger Description. Useful if you cannot do Modelbinding because the uploaded Data is too large.
/// Set the type to "file" if you want files. Otherwise all supported primitve swagger-types should be ok.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class SwaggerFormParameter : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    public CollectionFormat CollectionFormat { get; set; }

    public SwaggerFormParameter(string name, string type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using an IOperationFilter

```cs
    public class AddRequiredParameters : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry s, ApiDescription a)
        {
            if (operation.operationId == "ControllerName_Upload")
            {
                if (operation.parameters == null)
                    operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
                operation.parameters.Add(
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        name = "bigupload",
                        @in = "body",
                        @default = "123",
                        type = "string",
                        description = "bla bla",
                        required = true
                    }
                );                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a full example: [SwaggerConfig.cs#L505](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L505)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great starting point!
I added a custom attribute which can be applied to a method and is picked up by the operation filter.

Comment: @ChristianSauer nice idea! using a custom attrib will get rid of that condition on the operationId, if you can share that code so others can benefit